# Why default proguard configurations in android sdk use keep *Annotation*

Tags: android, annotations, proguard

There is one line in the default proguard configuration of android sdk:

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

According to Proguard Manual, this line equals to:

```
-keepattributes RuntimeVisibleAnnotations,RuntimeInvisibleAnnotations,RuntimeVisibleParameterAnnotations,RuntimeInvisibleParameterAnnotations,RuntimeVisibleTypeAnnotations,RuntimeInvisibleTypeAnnotations,AnnotationDefault
```

In my opinion, maybe the configuration below is enough:

```
-keepattributes RuntimeVisibleAnnotations,RuntimeVisibleParameterAnnotations,RuntimeVisibleTypeAnnotations,AnnotationDefault
```

Have I missing something? Why the recommend configuration keep all this things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, your observation is correct, the following configuration would be more correct imho:

```
-keepattributes RuntimeVisible*Annotation*,AnnotationDefault
```

Most people probably don't care about the subtle difference between runtime visible and invisible annotations, but there is no specific reason to keep runtime invisible annotations.

Edit: the above applies for Android applications only. If you are building an Android library, you should stick to -keepattributes *Annotation*.

btw. DexGuard (commercial variant of ProGuard) uses the updated configuration that I suggested above.

Comment: **applies for Android applications only. If you are building an Android library, you should stick to -keepattributes *Annotation\*** -- Thank you for pointing this out !