# Keep specific Annotation with proguard

Tags: java, android, annotations, proguard

I have two types of annotation in my project: `Annotation1` and `Annotation2`. Both are runtime annotations. So, my question is how to keep only `Annotation1` and strip `Annotation2`?

Example:

```
class Test {
    @Annotation1
    @Annotation2
    String name;
}
```

I want `Annotation2` to be removed from all fields and `Annotation1` to be kept everywhere.

I can't find whether this is possible. I only know how to keep all annotations using:

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

Is this possible? If not, why?

Answer (score 2):

ProGuard automatically removes annotations from the classes/fields/methods if the corresponding annotation classes are not used (retrieved, cast, invoked,...) elsewhere. You can't force ProGuard to remove annotations, but you can tell it to keep seemingly unused annotations:

```
-keep @interface com.example.MyAnnotation
```

Comment: This question isn't about keeping the annotation classes, it's about keeping them _applied_ where they are used.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same, but after considering the documentation at great length, and related questions on Stack Overflow, my conclusion is **this is not supported**.

At the time of writing, [only the following options related to annotations](https://www.guardsquare.com/manual/configuration/attributes) can be passed to `-keepattributes`. For *runtime visible* annotations:

- `RuntimeVisibleAnnotations`: keep *all* annotations on classes, fields, and methods
- `RuntimeVisibleParameterAnnotations`: keep *all* annotations on method parameters
- `RuntimeVisibleTypeAnnotations`: keep *all* annotations on generic types, instructions, etc. (not certain what ".etc" is supposed to mean here)

Matching selections for *runtime invisible* annotations are: `RuntimeInvisibleAnnotations`, `RuntimeInvisibleParameterAnnotations`,  and `RuntimeInvisibleTypeAnnotations`. [I couldn't find any use case for retaining these.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40255308/590790)

Lastly `AnnotationDefault` retains annotation default values.

In my opinion, the wildcard options for `-keepattributes` (`?` and `*`) do more harm than good. They are easily misinterpreted (like I originally did, [and others do](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7378693/590790), and you seem to desire) as a way to specify *specific* annotations, but this is not the case.

The common `-keepattributes *Annotation*` option simply selects all of the options listed above.