# Keep selected Annotations with proguard

Tags: proguard

Is it even possible to keep selected Annotations with Proguard?

For instance I would like to remove all annotations from

```
javax.xml.bind.annotation.*
```

But keep all from from

```
org.mycompany.annotations.MyAnnotation
```

I was trying to tell to Proguard to keep annotetion like below but does not work at all.

```
-keep @interface org.mycompany.annotations.MyAnnotation
```

Or should I keepattributes *Annotation* and then remove somehow rest of not needed annotations?

Comment: Just curious what do you want to achieve by removing annotation, code might not work at runtime. Am I missing something ?

Comment: It is quite simple. For instance you have an annotation MyModelClass which is used by for instance reflection. You need this one but you don't need some annotation from jaxb for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood completely, generally we retain all annotations by using

`-keepattributes *Annotation*`,

If you remove this from **-keepAttributes** list you will lose other annotation too, and code might not work.

Ideally I will play with classes on which annotation is applied , not the annotation itself, for instance if you have annotation MyModelClass which is applied on MyService class

```
 @ MyModelClass
    public class MyService {
    }
```

and I want nothing to happen to MyService class, then I will use

```
-keep @MyModelClass class * {
    <methods>;
    <fields>;
}
```

As you mentioned you don't need some jaxb annotation, I assume they are compile time annotation.

> In case you want to remove all compile time Annnotations and retain runtime annotation probably you should use `-keepattributes RuntimeVisibleAnnotations`

Comment: Maybe wrong example. Both my annotations are runtime and annotated the same classes.

Comment: so what do you want ? I guess you don't want annotation to be removed when proguard optimise the code or you want do keep those classes unchanged wherever these annotation is applied .

Comment: Let's look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47515093/keep-specific-annotation-with-proguard I want to keep class and Annotation1. So as an output I wanna to have class annotated only by Annotation1 even both are runtime. Is it clear right now?

Comment: Thanks for the link, even I could remember few of my comments there which I almost forgot. I am sorry but I am stuck at same point, If you don't need a runtime annotation, why don't you remove it from code on the first place instead of relying on proguard. or is there is something which I am missing