# Proguard: keep data class member information that has property with specific annotation

Tags: android, kotlin, annotations, proguard

I am currently creating a library for private use which provides an Annotation (lets call it `@Something`) which can be used on Properties of a data class. I created the annotation like so:

```
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY)
annotation class Something
```

It will be used like this

```
data class SomeDataClass (val param1: String, @Something val param2: String, val param3: String)
```

I then want to be able to access the following things on the class that contains properties with this annotation:

- memberFunctions (to get the copy constructor)
- parameters of the copy constructor
- memberProperties
- property annotations
- property name
- List item

Now everything works properly until I minify my library with ProGuard. As I understand it, I need to describe my ProGuard rules in `consumer-rules.pro`. But what exactly do I need to add here? I want every data class in the application that uses my library that has a property annotated with `@Something` to be kept so I can read the things above from it.

Comment: Have you tried using [`@androidx.annotation.Keep`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/annotation/Keep) before writing your own annotation?

Comment: try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47515093/keep-specific-annotation-with-proguard

Comment: The annotation I created in my library should be used outside of the library, so I need to make sure every class outside of the library that uses it is kept by ProGuard. I can't add @Keep to classes I don't own, right?

And doesn't `-keep class Annotation1{*;}` just keep the annotation but not all the other stuff I want to keep?